# Compare entire column with one data point

Tags: google-sheets

I want to check column A2:A which contains dates and add together all of C2:C where A2:A contains todays date, I've tried to use SUMIF to complete this; however, it seems this only adds all of it together if all the dates are today's date.

at the moment I have tried `=SUMIF(A2:A, A2:A=TODAY(), C2:C)`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `=sumif(A:A,today(),C:C)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

`=sum(filter(C2:C, A2:A=today()))`

(This was not tested)

Please let me know if you have any questions or if this does not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

FILTER also works. If you wanted to use SUMIF

```
=SUMIF(A2:A,TODAY(),C2:C)
```

with SUMIF, use the condition first. However, if you were using SUMIFS, you'd use the sum range first

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C,A2:A,TODAY())
```